# Javascript Spinner. Anyone knows one?

Tags: javascript, jquery, spinner

I am developing a Rails 3 site.
I need to show a control which is used to define periods of time: Ex. 10 minutes, 20 minutes, 1 hour in the following format:  0:10 , 0:20, 1:00.

The control must have a spinner (up and down arrows to increase or decrease in 10 minutes period).

Anyone knows a good, easy and portable JS spinner to use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like [spin.js](http://fgnass.github.com/spin.js/) perhaps? I've used it in the past and it's really simple and lightweight.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an animated picture.
Then used hide() and show() on the image.

Comment: He is talking about a spinner where there is an input then an up and down arrow to change it's value, not an image like a loading gif.